# d3js open a new tab with the country id in map chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working on this project and I have a map chart.
I am using a geojson link for getting the data for all the map.
What I want to do is when I click on any country, to take me to another link, with the ID of that specific country.
I have to use two datasets, one for visualizing the map from geojson file and the other one for my actual data. How can I use two datasets in one single element of d3

The Code snipped is below this:

```js
var margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([10000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 50000000, 100000000, 500000000, 1500000000])
    .range(["rgb(247,251,255)", "rgb(222,235,247)", "rgb(198,219,239)", "rgb(158,202,225)", "rgb(107,174,214)", "rgb(66,146,198)", "rgb(33,113,181)", "rgb(8,81,156)", "rgb(8,48,107)", "rgb(3,19,43)"]);

var path = d3.geoPath();

var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'map');

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(130)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 1.5]);

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);


var myTable = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "China",
        "population": "1330141295"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "India",
        "population": "1173108018"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "United States",
        "population": "310232800"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Indonesia",
        "population": "242968342"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Russia",
        "population": "201103330"
    }
];




queue()
         .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f/raw/a45e8709648cafbbf01c78c76dfa53e31087e713/world_countries.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f/raw/a45e8709648cafbbf01c78c76dfa53e31087e713/world_population.tsv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, data, population) {
    var populationById = {};

    population.forEach(function(d) {
        populationById[d.id] = +d.population;
    });
    data.features.forEach(function(d) {
        d.population = populationById[d.id]
    });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "countries")
        .selectAll("#map")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(populationById[d.id]);
        })
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .on('click', function (d, i) {
            var win = window.open('https://www.google.com/'+d.id , '_blank');
            win.focus();
        })
        
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(data.features, function(a, b) {
            return a.id !== b.id;
        }))
        // .datum(topojson.mesh(data.features, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "names")
        .attr("d", path);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.0/d3-tip.js"></script>
    
        <div id="map"></div>
```

Notice: the onclick function works all good right now but if I click on Russia for example, it would give me the id of that geojson file for Russia which is "RUS" but actually I need the id from myTable which is "5" for Russia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a country name from the datum of data you're using for your map, then lookup the id in myTable var.

So, your event would be

```
  .on('click', datum => {
        //Get the name of the country
        console.log(datum.properties.name);
        // Look up id by the name
        data = myTable.find(e => e.name === datum.properties.name)
        console.log(data.id) // here is your country id
        var win = window.open('https://www.google.com/'+data.id , '_blank');
        win.focus();
    })
```

EDIT: added a code snippet that print a URL with country id. If you click on Russia, you should be able to see it :)

```js
var margin = {
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([10000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 50000000, 100000000, 500000000, 1500000000])
    .range(["rgb(247,251,255)", "rgb(222,235,247)", "rgb(198,219,239)", "rgb(158,202,225)", "rgb(107,174,214)", "rgb(66,146,198)", "rgb(33,113,181)", "rgb(8,81,156)", "rgb(8,48,107)", "rgb(3,19,43)"]);

var path = d3.geoPath();

var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'map');

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(130)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 1.5]);

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);


var myTable = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "China",
        "population": "1330141295"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "India",
        "population": "1173108018"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "United States",
        "population": "310232800"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Indonesia",
        "population": "242968342"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Russia",
        "population": "201103330"
    }
];




queue()
         .defer(d3.json, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f/raw/a45e8709648cafbbf01c78c76dfa53e31087e713/world_countries.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f/raw/a45e8709648cafbbf01c78c76dfa53e31087e713/world_population.tsv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, data, population) {
    var populationById = {};

    population.forEach(function(d) {
        populationById[d.id] = +d.population;
    });
    data.features.forEach(function(d) {
        d.population = populationById[d.id]
    });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "countries")
        .selectAll("#map")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(populationById[d.id]);
        })
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
         .on('click', datum => {
    //Get the name of the country
    console.log(datum.properties.name);
    // Look up id by the name
    data = myTable.find(e => e.name === datum.properties.name)
    console.log('https://www.google.com/'+data.id) // here is your country id

})
        
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(data.features, function(a, b) {
            return a.id !== b.id;
        }))
        // .datum(topojson.mesh(data.features, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "names")
        .attr("d", path);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.0/d3-tip.js"></script>
    
        <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I get this error: **myTable.find is not a function** . Can you explain me how datum works ? Because I don't see where it is initialized with both datasets

Comment: Sure, datum is a d3 way of getting element information - link to docs - https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_datum. You can console log to see the whole datum to get the idea.

Comment: @Leo I've added a code snippet for your reference to the answer)

Comment: Looks all good. I decided to work with those geojson data insead. It has an ID too so I had to reconstruct my database and make it work with the given ID. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. Much appreaciated.

Comment: @Leo no problem!